# unable to start mysqld

Tags: raspberry-pi, mysql, startup, systemctl, arch-arm

I'm getting the following after I try to start mysql:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[pi@raspi ~]$ systemctl status mysqld
* mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.5 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-08-23 08:34:44 PDT; 9s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 466 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 467 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/S>
    Process: 479 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 479 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.4.14.
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi mariadbd[479]: 2020-08-23  8:34:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 08:34:44 raspi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.5 database server.
lines 1-21/21 (END)
```

I don't see any information from `syslog-ng` in `/var/log/messages.log` either....

I'm not sure what's going on, can anybody help me out with this? :o

As @tetech suggested, I should downgrade to a previous version of my mariadb package. So I tried:

```
[pi@raspi pkg]$ sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz 
[sudo] password for pi: 
loading packages...
warning: downgrading package mariadb (10.5.5-1 => 10.4.14-1)
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "mariadb-clients=10.4.14", a dependency of "mariadb"
:: The following package cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      mariadb

:: Do you want to skip the above package for this upgrade? [y/N] n
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: unable to satisfy dependency 'mariadb-clients=10.4.14' required by mariadb
[pi@raspi pkg]$ sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-clients-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz 
loading packages...
warning: downgrading package mariadb-clients (10.5.5-1 => 10.4.14-1)
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "mariadb-libs=10.4.14", a dependency of "mariadb-clients"
:: The following package cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      mariadb-clients

:: Do you want to skip the above package for this upgrade? [y/N] 
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: unable to satisfy dependency 'mariadb-libs=10.4.14' required by mariadb-clients
[pi@raspi pkg]$ sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-libs-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz    
loading packages...
warning: downgrading package mariadb-libs (10.5.5-1 => 10.4.14-1)
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing mariadb-libs (10.4.14-1) breaks dependency 'mariadb-libs=10.5.5' required by mariadb-clients
[pi@raspi pkg]$ sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-clients-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz 
loading packages...
warning: downgrading package mariadb-clients (10.5.5-1 => 10.4.14-1)
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "mariadb-libs=10.4.14", a dependency of "mariadb-clients"
:: The following package cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      mariadb-clients

:: Do you want to skip the above package for this upgrade? [y/N] 
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: unable to satisfy dependency 'mariadb-libs=10.4.14' required by mariadb-clients
```

But it seems like `mariadb-libs` is complaining about `mariadb-clients` and vice-versa. How do I get thenm downgraded? I'm now thinking it might just be easier to re-init my db instead....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to downgrade the mysql server was:

```
$ sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-clients-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-libs-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mariadb-10.4.14-1-aarch64.pkg.tar.xz
```

after this, I was able to start my MySql server again just fine and I have to look into how to properly upgrade it now.

Answer (score 1):

Notable error is `InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.4.14.`

It appears you have not properly stopped the DB and then upgraded it.

You'll need to either downgrade to 10.4.14 and do a recovery, or alternatively re-initialize and then restore the backup you took before upgrading.

Comment: See the update above.... do you know how to get around this? Otherwise, I'll "just" re-init

Comment: Typically all mariadb packages would need to be downgraded at the same time, so downgrade mariadb-clients too.  If that doesn't work, you might be able to (temporarily) uninstall it (if no dependencies).  Otherwise reinit.

Answer (score 1):

My solution on Manjaro Linux was to `sudo pacman -s downgrade` then run

```
downgrade mariadb-libs mariadb-clients mariadb
```

Downgrade lets you chose which version to downgrade to as well. Super easy, worked like a charm.